# Как добавить в мапу с помощью стрима не теряя порядка вхождения?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Мой код

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(textfile.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")).parallel();
Map<String, Integer> counter = stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Стрим ложит в мапу ключ стринг со интовым значение, который считает количество этой стринги в тексте

Проблема в том, что теряется последовательность вхождений

Например, входящая строка:

```
today is nice day today is
```

правильный вывод

```
{today=2, is=2, nice=1, day=1}
```

мой вывод

```
{today=2, is=2, day=1, nice=1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `LinkedHashMap`

```
Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new)
```